# Error (401) de permisos al subir archivo desde formulario en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Cuando se sube el archivo y se mueve a la carpeta especificada para poder acceder desde una URL arroja error 401, solo puedo visualizar el archivo de forma manual si entro a la carpeta contenedora y lo copio, pego y abro en otra carpeta como Documents, ¿será un problema típico de laravel o mi servidor IIS?

Así muevo el archivo:

```
if (!empty($request->pdf)) {
     $path        = "docs/pdf/";
     $fileName    = 'reference-'.time().'.pdf';
     $request->pdf->move(public_path($path), $fileName);
     $data['pdf'] = "pdf/{$fileName}";
}
```

¿Hay alguna forma de establecerle permisos publicos o algo por el estilo?

Comment: Asegurate que apache ( www-data en caso de ubuntu ) tiene acceso de escritura em ese directorio

Comment: 401 pareciera ser un error de autenticación. Podrías mostrar las rutas con sus middlewares y funciones de controller completas para ver como las tenes creadas?